# Using a POST request's response values in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, post, state

everyone. I'm a new developer and this is my first post here, so please bear with me.
What I'm trying to do is access the values that I received from a POST request that I made.

Below you can see what I'm trying to do. I set up a state where I'll store my data and then there's a function called fetchData that does a POST request and receives an object with the values, right?

Now I that I've received my object, I want to store its values in some of my variables.

Since the values have been stored in the 'data' state, I thought I would access its values by doing something like 'userName = data.userName', or something like 'age = data.userAge'. Obviously that didn't work out because my IDE does not know those values yet lol. So how do you think I should access them?

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData({
      ids: [0],
    })
      .then((response: any) => {
        setData(response);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: You overcomplicated your solution. don't use `useEffect`, not store an array with an empty object. 
My recommendation: go through a few tutorials first, then ask more specific.

Comment: What tutorials would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont place the function directly in useEffect, do something like this instead

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const getData = async() => {
 try{
  const response = await fetchData({ids: [0]});
  setData(response);
 }catch(error){
  console.log(error);
 }
}

useEffect(() => {
getData();
},[])
```

Comment: I see, I see. But why is it a bad idea to put a function inside useEffect instead of this?

Comment: Using .then when writing react-native code is not the most optimal approach. React-native utilises ES6 syntax, which means that you should rely on await & try-catch block statements, rather then .then. With that said, you cant use await inside useEffect since you cant declare it as async function, which is why you have to pre-define the async function as done above.

Comment: I suppose this should be the correct answer in that case :)